# Embedded Qt WebEngine security risk

Tags: qt, security, qnetworkaccessmanager, qwebengineview

In my QT application, I need to download certain data. This data is protected and users need to Login to the website to download the data. In order to allow users to login, I display the Login Page of our website using `QWebEngineView`. The user enters his credentials. This generates the required cookies for authentication. I store the generated cookies in `QNetworkCookieJar`. I then create a `QNetworkAccessManager` and add the saved `QNetworkCookieJar` to `QNetworkAccessManager`. I then use the `QNetworkAccessManager` to download the data. This all works fine. However, in the security review of my project, there were concerns raised that the Login page is under the control of my application and thus I can get the user credentials (for eg. by watching the keystrokes on Login Page).

So my question is: Is this security risk real? Can I actually get the user credentials? If yes. what options do I have to authenticate the user and still avoid any security loopholes?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in a Qt Application you can always catch any keystrokes sent to a widget. The same applies to Google Chrome and almost every web browser out there.  The user enters the data in the application and it is passed through to the network and across the wires to the web server.

When considering security risk you always consider two things. The potential damage and the feasibility of crafting an exploit.  The potential damage is high and you can't control that. What you can control is the feasibility of creating an exploit.  Considering that you (or your company) control the code, you can make it very hard to exploit the fact that your application knows the credentials. That would make the risk very low.

Even employing something like a hardware dongle would be problem because you have to transfer the data from the dongle to the the web engine. That still can provide a way to intercept it.

Try looking for discussions on software security risk analysis and mitigation. There is even an SE site about it, https://security.stackexchange.com/.